# How to use Bitcoin Core on a laptop as a hardware wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, electrum, offline, qrcode

I would like to have the following setup:

1. Bitcoin Core on an offline laptop. Here the private keys are stored. Full disk encryption.
2. Bitcoin Core on an online laptop. Here watch-only addresses from the private keys in the offline laptop are imported to monitor funds without exposing the private keys online. The blockchain is fully synced. Also full disk encryption.

I have already downloaded the entire blockchain and it's synced on one laptop. Now im wondering how can I use the other laptop as a hardware wallet and broadcast transactions in the online node. As far as I know even if there isn't proper support for this like Electrum for some reason, it is doable. I reckon reading something about this and it was done with QR codes or something. I also would like to make this through the GUI to minimize screwing up in the process.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do exactly what you are asking, but I think you could use some wallet like Wasabi. Run it on the offline laptop with encrypted disk, and connect to local full node (bitcoind running on your online laptop) through local IP address. You can configure Wasabi to do that in the settings.

I use similar setup where my Wasabi wallet connects to a full node run through Umbrel on a separate computer on the same network.

Comment: I would like to use Bitcoin Core. Im only familiar with Bitcoin Core and I like the coin control features better than in any other wallet.

Comment: Coin control is supported in lot of other wallets. Infact you can freeze some coins in other wallets and it will stay freezed even when you restart wallet. Bitcoin Core does not save locked coins in database so they will unlock on restart.